# How to animate a mesh created outside init() in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am learning three.js and would like to understand how to animate a mesh created by a function outside the regular init().

I'm able to create a cube inside init() and rotate it inside animate(), but if the cube is created by a function outside init() the console says that cube is not defined.

Here's a quick example : http://jsfiddle.net/mattsparrer/yqbp5hx4/10/

```
function createCube(size) {
    var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(size, size, size);
    var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

    cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);
    }
```

By searching on the web I understand "cube" is not in the scope of animate(), but I can't find the proper way to do it.
Please can someone explain the way to go ?

Comment: I've changed a bit the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/uotj19g5/)

Comment: Thanks for your help @prisoner849 I was looking for something like bind() or creating a loop like the example from Yakudoo, but in fact it was a bit obvious to create the cube before animate it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't so much a Three.js question, but more of a JavaScript *variable scope* question.

If you declare the `cube` variable within the `init()` function, it will only be available inside `init()`, but not inside `render()`. You have to declare it **outside** both these functions for it to be available to both.

**Wrong:**

```
function init(){
    // Declaring cube inside this function limits its scope
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh();
}

function render(){
    // Cube is not defined.
    // it's only available within the init() function.
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
}

console.log(cube); // Cube is also not defined out here.
```

---

**Correct:**

```
// Declare cube in global scope so both functions can "see" this variable
var cube;

function init(){
    // Assigns value to existing cube var
    cube = new THREE.Mesh();
}

function render(){
    // cube is also available inside this function
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
}

console.log(cube); // No error, because cube exists out here too
```

For more examples about variable scope, see here: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks @Marquizzo I tried it before posting, my mistake was to believe that the place of animate() in the script wasn't important

Comment: Ah, order of operations is also very important. If you call `animate` before calling `createCube` then there won't be any cube to animate! It should be 1: `init();` 2:`createCube(150);` and 3: `animate();`